# Opening hours go over midnight

Tags: schema.org, microdata

Is it possible to set an opening time which goes, for example, from 22:00 to 03:00?

It’s not defined in the description of Schema.org’s [`openingHours`](http://schema.org/openingHours). If it’s not working with `openingHours`, does it work with the properties [`opens`](http://schema.org/opens)/[`closes`](http://schema.org/closes) from [`OpeningHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification)?

For example like this:

```html
<div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope 
       itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">Mo,
     <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" 
           href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday" />
     <meta itemprop="opens" content="22:00:00">22:00 -
     <meta itemprop="closes" content="03:00:00">03:00
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t have any experience with this, but I would have assumed that using [`opens`](http://schema.org/opens) and [`closes`](http://schema.org/closes) like that should be fine, as their descriptions say

> The opening hour of the place or service on the given day(s) of the week.
>   The closing hour of the place or service on the given day(s) of the week.

and on "the given day(s) of the week", the opening hour *is* 22:00, and the closing hour *is* 03:00, no matter if that’s the closing hour of the previous opening or not.

However, [Martin Hepp explained in an email](http://ebusiness-unibw.org/pipermail/goodrelations/2012-September/000475.html) how `OpeningHoursSpecification` from his GoodRelations vocabulary should be used, and as Schema.org’s class is derived from this, it might be relevant:

> I.e., opening hours that cross midnight must be broken into two chunks, one opening hour specification for the first day, then closing at 23:59:59, and one for the next day of the week, opening ant 00:00:00.

So according to this, you would have to use something (ugly) like this:

```html
<div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
 <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Monday" />
 <meta itemprop="opens" content="22:00:00">
 <meta itemprop="closes" content="23:59:59">
</div>

<div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
 <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Tuesday" />
 <meta itemprop="opens" content="00:00:00">
 <meta itemprop="closes" content="03:00:00">
</div>

<div itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
 <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#Tuesday" />
 <meta itemprop="opens" content="22:00:00">
 <meta itemprop="closes" content="23:59:59">
</div>
```

(Instead of repeating it for each day, you could specify it in two `OpeningHoursSpecification` with multiple `dayOfWeek`, unless the times are different, of course.)

Comment: Note: I’ve opened [an issue about this](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/534 "GitHub: OpeningHoursSpecification for a place that is open past midnight").